# В чем проблема Unexpected token <?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Мой главный jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Header from './components/header/header'

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('wrapper'))
```

components/header/header.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <header className="header_block">
       <div className="header_block-logo"></div>
       <div className="header_block-score">
         Score:
         <span className="header_block-score_curr" id="score">0</span>
       </div>
     </header>
   );
 }
}

export default Header;
```

Мой проект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При сборке ошибка выскакивает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Ведь в ReactDOM.render нужно добавить `<Header />`

Чего он ругается?

UPDATE:
мой package.json:

```
{
 "name": "songbird",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "clean": "rm -f -r dist",
   "build-dev": "webpack -d --mode development",
   "build-prod": "webpack -p",
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --hot --mode development"
 },
 "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "git+https://github.com/kirillleogky/songbird.git"
 },
 "author": "Kirill Leogky",
 "license": "ISC",
 "bugs": {
   "url": "https://github.com/kirillleogky/songbird/issues"
 },
 "homepage": "https://github.com/kirillleogky/songbird#readme",
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
   "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
   "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
   "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
   "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
   "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
   "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
   "eslint": "^6.8.0",
   "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
   "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
   "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
   "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
   "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.3.0",
   "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
   "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
   "prettier": "^1.19.1",
   "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
   "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
   "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
   "webpack": "^4.41.5",
   "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^16.12.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: package.json можно посмотреть?

Comment: @Aleksandr скинул

Comment: еще бы файл конфигурации webpack

Answer (score 1):

У вас файл `.babelrc` находится в `dist` папке, а должен быть в корне (рядом с другими конфигурационными файлам: `.eslintrc`, `webpack.config.js`).

Comment: верно, без правильного расположения `.babelrc` не запускаются плагины и пресеты *Babel*, собственно, из-за этого Webpack не понимает синтаксис `jsx` и жалуется на него